# Can I use $q.all when one of the functions in the array does not return a promise?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this function that I would like to return a promise:

```
homeWordsResolve = (): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    var self = this;
    return this.$q.all([
        self.ens.getUserProfile(),
        self.wos.getWordsOrderBy(),
        self.wos.getPos()
    ]);
}
```

However one of the functions is synchronous and just returns a void.

```
getWordsOrderBy = (): void => {
    this.wordsOrderBy = this.ens.getOrderBy(EnumGetOrderBy.Word)
}
```

Is there some way that I could still keep using $q.all and perhaps modify the getWordsOrderBy to return a promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, `$q.all` accepts an array of promises or values.

```
$q.all([
  $q.resolve(1),
  $q.resolve(2),
  3
])
.then(function(results) {
  console.log(results);
});
```

will print `1, 2, 3`